# Implement tree builder with F#

Tags: algorithm, f#

I am pretty new to F# and I wanted to implement a solution to the following problem:
From a sequence of disk paths discovered in random order (e.g. "C:\Hello\foo" "C:" , "C:\Hello\bar" etc....) how to build (efficiently) the tree.
Assumption: the sequence is valid, which means the tree can be effectively created.

So I tried to implement with a recursive function ("mergeInto" in the following) which merges the tree "in place" with a list of string (the splitted path called "branch")

Here is my implementation, the immutability prevents side effects on the input tree, so I tried to use a ref cell for the input Tree but I encounter difficulty with the recursion. Any solution ?

```
open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

type Tree =
    |Node of string*list<Tree>
    |Empty

let rec branchToTree (inputList:list<string>) =
    match inputList with
        | [] -> Tree.Empty
        | head::tail ->  Tree.Node (head, [branchToTree tail])

//branch cannot be empty list
let rec mergeInto (tree:Tree ref) (branch:list<string>) =
    match !tree,branch with
        | Node (value,_), head::tail when String.op_Inequality(value, head) -> raise (ApplicationException("Oops invariant loop broken"))
        | Node (value,_), [_] -> ignore() //the branch is singleton and by loop invariant its head is the current Tree node -> nothing to do.
        | Node (value,children), _ -> 
                                let nextBranchValue = branch.Tail.Head //valid because of previous match

                                //broken attempt to retrieve a ref to the proper child
                                let targetChild = children 
                                                |> List.map (fun(child) -> ref child)
                                                |> List.tryFind (fun(child) -> match !child with
                                                                                        |Empty -> false
                                                                                        |Node (value,_) -> value = nextBranchValue)
                                match targetChild with
                                    |Some x -> mergeInto x branch.Tail //a valid child match then go deeper. NB: branch.Tail cannot be empty here
                                    |None -> tree := Node(value, (Node (nextBranchValue,[])) :: children)//attach the next branch value to the children
        | Empty,_ -> tree := branchToTree branch

[<TestClass>]
type TreeTests () = 
    [<TestMethod>]
    member this.BuildTree () =
        let initialTree = ref Tree.Empty
        let branch1 = ["a";"b";"c"]
        let branch2 = ["a";"b";"d"]

        do mergeInto initialTree branch1
        //-> my tree is ok
        do mergeInto initialTree branch2
        //->not ok, expected a
        //                   |
        //                   b
        //                  / \
        //                 d   c
```

Comment: "You encounter difficulty with the recursion" - A compile or run time error?

Comment: it compiles fine but the result is not the expected one (see second do statement in the test at the bottom of the code block). The "side effect" within the recursion call is not taken into account. But in the first level of recursion it is ok (see first do statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a `ref` to an element in a `list`, change the `ref` and then expect the item in the `list` to change. If you really want to do that then you should put the references into your `Tree` type.

```
type Tree =
    |Node of string*list<Tree ref>
    |Empty

let rec branchToTree (inputList:list<string>) =
    match inputList with
        | [] -> Tree.Empty
        | head::tail ->  Tree.Node(head, [ref (branchToTree tail)])
```

If you do that, remove the `List.map (fun(child) -> ref child)` part then your code works.

You might be interested in [zippers](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2010/12/30/f-zipper-with-pipe-forward) which allow you to do something similar but without mutation.

Comment: This solves my problem, however it forces me to change the data structure for this particular construction. Maybe, other usages of "my" tree type would not require the ref cell. I will read carefully your link about the zippers. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, the zippers were exactly what I was looking for. I reviewed the algorithm and wrote a post: [link]http://benoitpatra.com/2013/07/24/rethink-a-basic-tree-algorithm-with-purely-functional-data-structures-the-zippers/